# Prepeared statement doesn´t like the AND LIKE ? when try to UPDATE the table filtered with id and date

Tags: sql

It all works without the

```
AND date LIKE ?
```

but with it it doesn't update the table. What am I doing wrong? $date looks like this:

```
2024-03%
```

and is created with $tableYear and $tableMonth.

Is anybody seeing a failure in the following part? I´m calling the script with an Ajax-request, so I don´t have an error-message.

```php
    $tableYear = $tableYEAR . "-" . $tableMonth;
    $date = $tableYear . "%";

    /*Prepare DB-Update*/
    $stmt_cashoutflag_update = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE stunden SET cash_out=? WHERE md5=? AND date LIKE ?");
    /*Bind params*/
    $stmt_cashoutflag_update->bind_param('iss', $flag, $idMD5, $date);
    /* Execute the prepared Statement */
    $stmt_cashoutflag_update->execute();
    /*Close the prepare Statement*/
    $stmt_cashoutflag_update->close();
```

I tried the code without the LIKE-part and it works. Otherwise it won´t update the table.
When I use the $date in a select-query:

```
$ergebnis_monatssaldo = $mysqli-\>query("SELECT summe FROM stunden WHERE md5 = '$cashoutID' AND date LIKE '$date' AND cash_out = '0';");
```

it is working as well.

I was not sure if "LIKE ?" is right.

var_dump($tableMonth) is giving: string(2) "03"

var_dump($date) is giving: string(8) "2024-03%"

[image]

Please don´t care about the word "datum". In my question I use "date" instead for better understanding.

As mentioned above the select-query works fine with the LIKE-date-part:

```
$ergebnis_monatssaldo = $mysqli-\>query("SELECT summe FROM stunden WHERE md5 = '$cashoutID' AND date LIKE '$date' AND cash_out = '0';");
```

[image: date/datum-column has type "date"]

[image: users have month-filter-buttons]

Thank you all for your helpfulness. Following solution did the job for me. Surely not the smoothest way but it works fine:

```
    if(isset($_POST['tableMonth'])){
          $tableYear = $tableYEAR . "-" . $tableMonth;
    
    
          $dateSTART = $tableYear . "-01";
    
          if($tableMonth == "01") {
            $monthEND = "-02";
          } else if($tableMonth == "02"){
            $monthEND = "-03";
          } else if($tableMonth == "03"){
            $monthEND = "-04";
          } else if($tableMonth == "04"){
            $monthEND = "-05";
          } else if($tableMonth == "05"){
            $monthEND = "-06";
          } else if($tableMonth == "06"){
            $monthEND = "-07";
          } else if($tableMonth == "07"){
            $monthEND = "-08";
          } else if($tableMonth == "08"){
            $monthEND = "-09";
          } else if($tableMonth == "09"){
            $monthEND = "-10";
          } else if($tableMonth == "10"){
            $monthEND = "-11";
          } else if($tableMonth == "11"){
            $monthEND = "-12";
          }
    
          $dateEND = $tableYEAR . $monthEND . "-01";
    
          
          if($tableMonth == "12"){
            $tableYEARNEXTYEAR = $tableYEAR + 1;
            $dateENDNEXTYEAR = $tableYEARNEXTYEAR . "-01-01";
          }
    
        }



/*Prepare DB-Update*/
    $stmt_cashoutflag_update = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE stunden SET cash_out=? WHERE md5=? AND datum>=? AND datum<?");
    /*Bind params*/
    $stmt_cashoutflag_update->bind_param('isss', $cashout_flag, $arbeiterCashoutBTNMonth, $dateSTART, $dateEND);
    /* Execute the prepared Statement */
    $stmt_cashoutflag_update->execute();
    /*Close the prepare Statement*/
    $stmt_cashoutflag_update->close();
```

Comment: The usage of LIKE ? in your prepared statement appears correct. To debug, ensure that $date holds the expected value. Echo or log $date before the update statement to verify its content.

Comment: What does `var_dump($tableMonth)` give you? `3`, `"3"` or `"03"`?

Comment: Thx for the answers: var_dump($tableMonth) is giving: string(2) "03"

var_dump($date) is giving: string(8) "2024-03%";

Comment: `select cast('2024-03-15' as datetime) like '2024-03%'` works as expected (not that I like it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a date range

```sql
AND date >= ? 
AND date < ?
```

where the two parameters would be the dates `2024-03-01` and `2024-04-01`. Pass these parameters as proper date values not strings.

Comment: The user is filtering the database with a month-filter-button. eg.: show me all entries for 2024-03. I just added a pic in the question for more clearness.

Comment: So? Just create a date value for the beginning of that month and the beginning of then next month, and pass them in as parameters. Don't use `LIKE`, that's meant for strings.

Comment: Ok, so did I get you right: $dateStart = "2024-03-01" and $dateEnd = "2024-04-01". With or without quotes?

Comment: Without quotes.

Comment: Thank you, this did the job, but I had to quote/unquote the date. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

A date datatype is not a string... You can compare date with strings (LIKE works only with string) only if you know the pattern the date will be convert from data datatype to string datatype... As an example, a date can be converted in dd/mm/yyyy if the user has openned his session in french or convert to mm/dd/yyyy when the user is english...

Comment: Ok, but why does it work in the select-query. Doing nothing else than comparing the date with the date in the date(datum)-column?

Comment: Another time date is not a string... It is a binary data of an undocumented form that can be casted to a string in a formated mask that depend of session parameters... In your query the predicate " date LIKE '2024-03%' " the value of the date column is converted implicitly into a string with a format that you ignore the mask...